# client.channels.cache.get('id') returns empty Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, discord.js

I want to get a channel with only an ID given. So the way the docs describe is like this: `client.channels.cache.get('channel id')`, and that's also how I am doing it.
But by printing out the cache I see that the cache Map is empty (length = 0).
The thing is, placing the `console.log(client.channels.cache)` in my client "ready" event listener, it gets printed out.

I read that this error could appear if the client is not logged in properly, but this can not be the case since I call the function with a command and the console log in the "ready" event listener is called instantly after the program is started and works better.

So there must be something else I am missing.

Comment: What version of `discord.js` are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the channel ID, you could simply [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) the channel by this ID. If it's cached, it returns the cached channel:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(CHANNEL_ID)

console.log(channel)
```

`fetch()` returns a Promise, so you'll need to use `await` in an async function, or `then` methods.

Comment: Okay so with your way, I got another error message telling me that at the moment I was executing the request for the channel, my client was not logged in (as I already thought). By simply adding client.login('TOKEN') in the function fixed it. I don't know if I could come up with problems from logging in twice in my code so if you know something about that please let me know.
But thank you for your answer. It helped finding a way <3

Comment: Not sure if I can understand _1,_ where you try to fetch the channel, _2,_ where you try to log in again.

Comment: I am calling a function from a command in discord (I assume you know how the setup roughly looks like when handling commands and calling the corresponding function). And in this function that is called from the command, I want to fetch the channel and right infront of that request, I now added a `client.login()`. Hope it's understandable